# Exporting excel values to Infopath

Tags: excel, infopath2010, vba

I have a database of Infopath forms and an Excel file with a macro to pull all of the data from multiple Infopath files into a spreadsheet using XMLMaps.Import.  Now, I would like a way to update the fields in an existing InfoPath form using Excel without creating a new form.

1. Is this possible?
2. What data is needed to make it happen?
3. A sample of vba code if possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**You could do this by using third party tool.
check this out :
http://www.qdabra.com/en/products/exceltoinfopath.aspx
http://www.qdabra.com/en/products/docs/library/Excel%20to%20InfoPath%20Tool%20Datasheet.pdf**